# Error connecting jboss cli in jboss-eap-6.2, also running web application was un accessible

Tags: jboss6.x

Application hosted in Jboss EAP 6.2 stalled and I can't connect it from CLI command.While trying to connect it is giving following error.

```
$ ./jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=localhost:9999
    org.jboss.as.cli.CliInitializationException: Failed to connect to the controller
            at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CliLauncher.initCommandContext(CliLauncher.java:284)
            at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CliLauncher.main(CliLauncher.java:262)
            at org.jboss.as.cli.CommandLineMain.main(CommandLineMain.java:34)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.modules.Module.run(Module.java:292)
            at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:455)
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.cli.CommandLineException: The controller is not available at localhost:9999
            at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.tryConnection(CommandContextImpl.java:969)
            at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.connectController(CommandContextImpl.java:808)
            at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.connectController(CommandContextImpl.java:784)
            at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CliLauncher.initCommandContext(CliLauncher.java:282)
            ... 8 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection timed out
            at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.executeForResult(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:129)
            at org.jboss.as.controller.client.impl.AbstractModelControllerClient.execute(AbstractModelControllerClient.java:71)
            at org.jboss.as.cli.impl.CommandContextImpl.tryConnection(CommandContextImpl.java:947)
            ... 11 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection timed out
```